# Issues with ROC curves of logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, roc

I did some analysis with my data but I found that all the ROC plots have the threshold points consolidated at the base of the graphs. Is the issue from the data itself or from the package used?

```
library(ROCR)
ROCRPred = prediction(res2, test_set$WRF)
ROCRPref <- performance(ROCRPred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(ROCRPref, colorize=TRUE, print.cutoffs.at=seq(0.1,by = 0.1))
```

[image: ROC curve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "the threshold points  are consolidated at the base of the graphs" due to the parameter 'print.cutoffs.at' in plot.

According to the documentation 
print.cutoffs.at:-This vector specifies the cutoffs which should be printed as text along the curve at the corresponding curve positions.

As mentioned by @Calimo in his answer to adapt the threshold according to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you choose cutoffs between 0.1 and 1?

```
print.cutoffs.at=seq(0.1,by = 0.1)
```

You need to adapt them to your data. For instance you could use the quantiles:

```
plot(ROCRPref, colorize=TRUE, print.cutoffs.at=quantile(res2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm actually a new learner of R programming, I saw this process on youtube and I can say it's very hard to follow for me. There are too many formulas to deal with. Anyways thanks for the reply

Comment: @davegas100 glad to hear that I could help. If this answers your question don't forget to accept it ;)